# Изменение значения использованной css-переменной

Tags: css, css-variables

Я ожидал, что в следующем коде получится синий div, а он красный. Как поправить?

```css
:root {
  --base-color: red;
  --color: var(--base-color);
}

main {
  --base-color: blue;
}

div {
  height: 3em;
  background: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

---

Более подробно: я хочу менять цвет в зависимости от темы и не переопределять для каждой из них вычисляемые значения, поскольку они одинаковы:

```css
:root {
  --base-color: red;
  --color: var(--base-color);
}

.theme1 {
  --base-color: green;
}

.theme2 {
  --base-color: blue;
}

div {
  padding: 1em;
  background: var(--color);
}

body * + * {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>Red</div>
</section>

<section class="theme1">
  <div>Green</div>
</section>

<section class="theme2">
  <div>Blue</div>
</section>
```

Пробовал поиграться с [`CSS.RegisterProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/RegisterProperty), но из этого ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 3):

Вполне ожидаемое поведение. По аналогии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот если `b` определить уже после того, как была изменена `a`, тогда все будет работать как ожидалось.

```css
:root {
  --base-color: red;
}

main {
  --base-color: blue;
  --color: var(--base-color);
}

div {
  height: 3em;
  background: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

---

Спасибо @Grundy за наводку.
Побочный эффект - придется апплаить дополнительный класс.

```css
:root {
  --base-color: red;

}

.use-vars {
  --color: var(--base-color);
}

.theme1 {
  --base-color: green;
}

.theme2 {
  --base-color: blue;
}

div {
  padding: 1em;
  background: var(--color);
}

body * + * {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="use-vars">Red</div>
</section>

<section class="use-vars theme1">
  <div>Green</div>
</section>

<section class="use-vars theme2">
  <div>Blue</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Сомнительная аналогия. Css-свойства наследуются, а js-переменные - нет. Повторять для каждой темы соответствия цветов, которые одинаковы для всех возможно, но неудобно. Ещё варианты есть?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. В твоём варианте получится, что надо сделать `:root, .theme1, .theme2 { --color: var(--base-color); }` - возможно, но не впечатляет. Что-то основанное на css-наследовании можно сделать?

Comment: Мне надо в разных местах страницы одновременно использовать разные темы. Так что пока сделал вариант с перечислением всех тем в селекторе, но т. к. они будут добавляться, получается, что надо в несколько мест изменения не забывать вносить... Под наследованием я имею в виду каскадность стилей вообще, а не только использование ключевого слова `inherit`. Ещё в `CSS.registerProperty` можно настраивать наследуемость, но мне пока не помогло.

Comment: @Qwertiy "То есть изменять значения базовых переменных в зависимости от выбранной темы?" - и при этом отказаться, разумеется, от derived-значений. Иначе говоря, выбросить либо `color` либо `base-color`, оставить что-то одно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вынеси все var в другой класс

Comment: @Grundy, есть вообще вариант влепить `* { --color: var(--base-color); }`, но ме кажется, это плохой способ?

Comment: @Qwertiy, не, `* { --color: var(--base-color); }` - чот не очень выглядит

Comment: @Grundy, но элемент с `use-vars` должен быть по dom-дереву не выше `theme1`, иначе возвращаемся к изначальной проблеме. А если он будет ниже, то это какой-то идиотизм с точке зрения архитектуры кода. Получается, они будут всегда идти парой.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135629/discussion-on-answer-by-smellyshovel----css-).