# CSS переменная не определяется

Tags: css, css-variables

Я определяю переменные цветов и потом совмещаю их в другой переменной, вставляя эту переменную в контейнер, я получаю все еще зеленый цвет, хотя я перезаписываю одну из них в потомке и должен получить по итогу синий цвет, но почему-то `--hsl` не видит, что я перезаписал переменную `--h` по каскаду. Как это работает? Что я делаю не так?

```css
:root {
  --h: 100;
  --s: 50%;
  --l: 50%;
  --hsl: hsl(var(--h), var(--s), var(--l));
}

.colored {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  --h: 200;
  background-color: var(--hsl);
}
```

```html
<div class="colored"></div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1401402/178988

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменение значения использованной css-переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1401402/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-css-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: Насколько я понимаю по каскаду наследуется значение переменной, т.е. `--hsl` вычислено в контексте `:root` и дальнейшие изменения `--h` его не волнуют. Но найти сходу доказательство в документации не могу.